# Python, Using variable 'saldo' before assignment

Tags: python, sintaxis

ante todo, perdón por mi código desordenado. Pero tengo un problema con la variable 'saldo' y no entiendo por qué me sale el error que describo en el título, de antemano, gracias por su ayuda.
Si tengo algo aparte que mejorar, lo pueden comentar igualmente.

```
import random
import requests
    #Definición de coneccion a la api binance

_ENDPOINT = "https://api.binance.com" #aqui definimos la base de la URL del API de binance
def _url(api):
        return _ENDPOINT+api
        #esta funciona toma la base  y le concatena lo que le agregamos como api

def get_price(cripto):
    return requests.get(_url("/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol="+cripto)) 

def esmoneda (cripto):
    return cripto in monedas
monedas=()
monedas_dic={}
saldo=30


headers = {  'Accepts': 'application/json',  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY':  '4f6bb077-95a9-479c-8b97-9c01ed91a61a'}
lista = []
data = requests.get("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest",headers=headers).json()

for cripto in data ["data"]:
    monedas_dic[cripto["symbol"]]=cripto["name"]

monedas = monedas_dic.keys()

for c in data["data"]:
    lista.append(c["symbol"])

listaTupla = tuple(lista)

def datos():
    moneda=input("Ingrese la moneda: ")
    cantidad=float(input("Ingrese la cantidad de "+moneda+": "))
    
    print("Nombre completo de la moneda: ", monedas_dic.get(moneda), 
    " Nombre código de la moneda: ", moneda)

    while not moneda in listaTupla:
        print("La moneda es inválida")
        moneda=input("Ingrese la moneda: ")
    else:
        print("Moneda correcta.")
        data = get_price(moneda+"USDT").json()
        print("El precio de",moneda,"es",data["price"])
        int(float(data["price"]))

        cotización=int(float(data["price"]))
        acumulado=cantidad*cotización
        print("Usted tiene ",acumulado,"USD de su moneda ",moneda)
        saldo=saldo+acumulado
        print("En total, en tu billetera dígital posees: ",saldo)

datos()
```

Hay 3 problemas con la misma variable, creo la variable saldo, la uso en la función y también un poco más abajo en algunos condicionales/bucles. La única forma de que lo "solucione" fue cambiando de nombre a datos, la variable que esta al comienzo a datos1, y aplicarlo a todos los "datos" que no fuesen de la función, pero en su funcionamiento, no hace lo que necesito, según vean el código se darán cuenta de lo que intentaba hacer.
Nuevamente gracias por su atención...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! se sugiere que tu codigo sea lo minimo posible para poder reproducir el problema... y no se entiende tu codigo, ni donde esta tirando el error....

Comment: @gbianchi Listo, lo hice más breve, creo que ahora se entiende mejor, ¿no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examinemos este caso:

```
saldo = 100

def sumar_saldo(monto):
    return saldo + monto

print(sumar_saldo(20))
```

Este código funciona, retorna e imprime el valor `120`, que es lo que intuitivamente esperas que pase.

En Python no necesitas *definir* una variable; simplemente la usas. Si quieres **tomar el valor** de una variable que no está definida dentro de la función (*scope* local o variable local), la va a buscar dentro del *scope* global (variable global).

En este caso, `saldo` es una variable global: está definida fuera de cualquier función y la puedes usar en cualquier parte del programa.

Otra cosa es cuando quiere **modificar una variable**. Para eso la variable debe haber sido inicializado primero dentro del mismo *scope*, o sea, debe ser una variable local a la función. Es una medida de seguridad para que no modifiques por error una variable global.

El siguiente código falla con error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'saldo' referenced before assignment`

```
saldo = 100

def sumar_saldo(monto):
    saldo += monto
    return saldo

print(sumar_saldo(20))
```

La razón es que dentro de `sumar_saldo` quieres modificar el valor de `saldo` sin haberlo inicializado previamente dentro de la misma función. Python entiende que `saldo` dentro de la función y el `saldo` fuera de ella son dos variables distintas, incluso si tienes el mismo nombre.

Tú tienes claro que te estas refiriendo a la variable global, pero tienes que decirlo explícitamente, usando la declaración `global saldo`, así

```
saldo = 100

def sumar_saldo(monto):
    global saldo
    saldo += monto
    return saldo

print(sumar_saldo(20))
```

Esto si funciona como esperas: el valor retornado es `120` y la variable global  `saldo` también queda modificada.

Todo esto es por razones prácticas: cuando estas escribiendo el cuerpo de una función, eres libre de usar cualquier nombre, incluso si el mismo nombre se usa en otras partes.

En resumen, tienes que agregar la declaración `global saldo` a tu función:

```
def datos():
    global saldo
    moneda=input("Ingrese la moneda: ")
    cantidad=float(input("Ingrese la cantidad de "+moneda+": "))
```

y asunto arreglado.

Answer (score -1):

```
sin usar tu código te muestro

 
saldo = 30  #las variables tienen un alcance fuera de las funciones por así decirlo

def sumar():
    global saldo  #acá defino la variable para que la contenga ya que está fuera de la función
    saldo+=1
    
sumar()   
print(saldo)
```

Comment: Una respuesta explica el error y su solución. Un trozo de código sin más no cumple ninguno de los dos requisitos.

Comment: ajá¿ y no está el por qué y la solución? ¿o hace falta un testamento para explicar lo más simple?

Comment: Eso mismo; hay que explicar hasta lo más simple. Tendrías que haber hablado de *scope*, del uso de *global*, de por qué puede *usar* una variable global sin más, pero tiene que declararla con `global` si la quiere *modificar*. Asi, cada vez que otro novato pregunte por lo mismo, simplemente se le dice que lea tu respuesta.

Comment: ¡definitivamente no!. prefiero orientar y no dar una clase, lo tuyo es subestimar al que lee e incentivarlo a que no busque unformación ya que das todo servido. Y sino cumplo los requisitos, bueno no pasa nada, no tengo obligación con esta página.